# Advice on structuring and rendering different objects within the same view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I'm building an application and I'm looking for some advice on how to structure a specific piece of functionality I'm working on.

I have this reports view, on this page a drop down with various reports a user can generate. This is what it looks like:

[image]

[image]

The drop down is just an array I hard coded in the controller. When a user selects a specific report, the controller makes a call to the ReportFactory and returns the selected report object, from there the view builds the report using the returned object.

However, this doesn't work with multiple reports since the html table is completely different depending on the report I need and as of now I've hard coded the report table into the view.

**What would be the best way to switch between different reports  which would each have their own function to build the object, their own html to render the table and where I can still implement DataTables to all of them once I get to that step.**

Comment: I'm still trying to implement ui.Router in my application first. If that solution ends up working for me I'll definitely accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly use a named ui-view with ui-router, then each dropdown would be a state which can load a different templateURL and controller.

Comment: So I'd have a view within my view for each report and these sub views would each have their own template and controller and the controller would just make a call to the ReportsFactory?

Comment: Yes, multiple views each with own template and controller. Check this for usage: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: This seems like it's going to work best, thank you for your suggestion. I managed to replace the ngRouter stuff in my app so now I'm going to try this, don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: How would I change the view/state using the dropbox though?